# How to Drag and Drop Outlook Message into browser with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, outlook

I am using vuejs for a project and I have come across something I cannot figure out. I need to be able to drag and drop a outlook message into the browser and capture the details from the email (to, from, cc, message body, subject, date received, message ID in header, etc). I have found another post which points to this API :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/items

However I am not sure I am able to use this with VueJS or what I would need to do to be able to use it since vuejs uses a virtual DOM. Any suggestions if this is even feasible would be great and a code example would be even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the API docs you sent, I created an example.
Here's a code pen!
https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/dyWVEbO?editors=1111

In the example you can click and drag an entire outlook email into the drop zone and it will insert all of the email text. You'll just need to do some processing of the input email string.

```
const myVue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    onDrop(ev){
      const emailData = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text')
      console.log(emailData)
      this.items.push(
        emailData
      )
    }
  }
})


function dragstart_handler(ev) {
 console.log("dragStart: target.id = " + ev.target.id);
 // Add this element's id to the drag payload so the drop handler will
 // know which element to add to its tree
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
 ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
 console.log("drop: target.id = " + ev.target.id);
 ev.preventDefault();
 // Get the id of the target and add the moved element to the target's DOM
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 myVue.onDrop(ev)
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
 console.log("dragOver");
 ev.preventDefault();
 // Set the dropEffect to move
 ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"
}
```

Comment: Wow that is impressive you were able to get the API to work. I think this response will help a lot of people.

Comment: Just curious regarding your answer  and using getData(). Is there a way to pull the files attached the outlook email as well? Basically the email includes various files in it that I will be uploading to the server as well. I see there is a datatransfer.files object but I think that refers to the actual outlook email.

Comment: I'm happy to help! Will the user be selecting all the text from the email or will they be selecting the attachment directly?

Comment: basically once I drag the email over to browser I will be laying out the email data like you did on the screen in your example in a veutify form, but I will also be listing out the attachments. These attachments hopefully clickable on the screen to open but ultimately these will be submitted/saved to the server with a POST request when form is submitted. I just need to figure out how to attach the files to browser once drag and dropped. I tried the datatransfer.files but doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: You might be able to use the "attachment" data type. I dragged an attachment in and got this:

```
"attachment" "{'itemType':'attachment','attachmentFile':{'attachmentItemId':'AAMkADBkOTUxM2E5LWUyODItNDhlYi05ZTc3LWNjNzhmNGQyZmFmYwBGAAAAAABrnSvzeA4cQ4FVhr7D91MyBwBKwDuR/SxrQJ6gzm4zcEszAAAAAAEMAABKwDuR/SxrQJ6gzm4zcEszAAHlL70NAAABEgAQAEn9evnmb5NAj6uJ1OgSBUY=','name':'template.html','size':5631,'fileType':5,'type':'ItemIdAttachment:#Exchange','ContentType':'text/html'}}"
```

https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/yLbvBgR?editors=1011

Comment: I could not find a way to select both the text + the attachments so I'm not certain this is possible the way you want to do it.

Comment: If I drag over the attachment into the drop zone nothing shows in console which is weird since for you it returns that array. I am also curious why text datatype and getData() does not include the body of the email or who it is sending to and any other contacts. You would think it could pull that information as well.

Comment: Ah I think I tested the attachment drag-drop with outlook on the browser rather than the desktop app. It doesn't appear to work on the desktop app.

Comment: Are you able to see more data fields such as body and the recipients ?